# Nativescript-vue: how to initialize DatePicker

Tags: nativescript-vue

**Goal:** I need to init a datepicker to be set to a max date of today  - 18 years (`birthDateMax`), and to save its value into `birthDate`

In `template` I have

```
<DatePicker class="date_not_choosen" 
            v-if="! birthDateSet" 
            maxDate="birthDateMax" 
            v-model="birthDate" 
/>
```

In `script` (note that I am using [`momentJs`](http://momentjs.com) library.

```
    data() {
        return {
            birthDateMax: moment().subtract(18, 'years').format('Y-MM-DD'),
            birthDate: this.birthDateMax,
        }
    }
```

**The problem:** when app starts, the date picker is set a 1970-01-01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `maxDate="birthDateMax"` with `:maxDate="birthDateMax"`.

The `:` is the shorthand to Vue's `v-bind:`, which is required to make the attribute `maxDate` reactive.